# Datepicker Jquery Set Second Date After Choosing First Date

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker

I am building an accommodation rental search form. The website is ASPX based and I am using the JS Jquery Datepicker setup with CSS to make it work.

I am able to make the date popup work and position correctly. However, when the website user chooses the first date, I need the second date popup window to open +2 days. Or the second date to be set to +2 days.

Does anyone know how to add JS code to my current setup to make this work? Any help would be greatly appreciated as I looked at several posts about this topic and could not get it to work.

Below is the JS that I am using so far:-

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#txtDate").datepicker({
    showOn: 'button',
    buttonText: 'Show Date',
    numberOfMonths:1,
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    buttonImage: '/images/cont/mobile/calendar.png'
});

$("#txtDate2").datepicker({
    showOn: 'button',
    buttonText: 'Show Date',
    numberOfMonths:1,
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    buttonImage: '/images/cont/mobile/calendar.png'
});

$(".ui-datepicker-trigger").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
});

});
</script>
```

And this is the HTML:-

```
<input type='text' id='txtDate' name="checkin" value=" " /> 

<input type="text" id="txtDate2" name="checkout" value=" " />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the selected date and add 2 days to it based on `onSelect` event of the first datepicker.

```js
$(function () {
  $("#txtDate").datepicker({
    //showOn: 'button',
    buttonText: 'Show Date',
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    buttonImage: '/images/cont/mobile/calendar.png',
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
      var txtDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
      txtDate.setDate(txtDate.getDate() + 2);
      $("#txtDate2").datepicker('setDate', txtDate);
    }
  });

  $("#txtDate2").datepicker({
    //showOn: 'button',
    buttonText: 'Show Date',
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    buttonImage: '/images/cont/mobile/calendar.png'
  });

  $(".ui-datepicker-trigger").mouseover(function () {
    $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='txtDate' name="checkin" value=" " />
<input type="text" id="txtDate2" name="checkout" value=" " />
```

Comment: That solution that works well and the second date field now updates with the date +2. Does anyone know how to get it so the date popup opens when the user puts the cursor in the date field? Right now the date popup  only opens the popup when the calendar graphic is clicked. I am guessing it has to do with the Jquery onClick setting. Maybe I should use something like onClick: datepicker();  ?

Comment: I think that I figured it out. I addedthis code and it seems to work.      $("#txtDate").click(function() {
        $(this).datepicker().datepicker( "show" )
    });

   $("#txtDate2").click(function() {
        $(this).datepicker().datepicker( "show" )
    });

Comment: Updated code above. Just disable `showOn` for both the date pickers.